# Percentages on votes

Tags: percentages

In an election 60% of votes cast their votes. There are 80,500 people in the area. In a contest between Mandy and Shah, Mandy won the elections by 1300 votes more than Shah. By what % of votes cast did Mandy win over Shah?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Have you done anything so far? The idea is NOT for us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Yes, i done level best. i couldn't get answer so i posted. By the way that isn't my homework.

Answer (score 1):

Total votes is equal to 60% of 80500 people:
total = 0.6*80500 = 48,300 votes

Mandy won by 1300 votes.

1300 votes out of 48,300 votes as a percentage:
1300/48300 = .0269 * 100 = 2.69%

Mandy won by 2.69% over Shah

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: Do you think you could figure out how the % would change if Mandy won by 1500 votes?

Comment: 1500/48300*100=3.10